# L’origine di -bb- nel passato remoto di “conoscere”, “crescere”, “avere”

Tags: etymology, past-tense

Il passato remoto di *conoscere*, nella primera persona singolare, è *conobbi*.  Da dove viene etimologicamente questa *-bb-* (che si usa anche nella terza persona singolare e plurale, *conobbe*, *conobbero*)?

In quali verbi si trova?  Apparentemente non solo in quelli che finiscono in *-escere*, perchè *avere* tiene come passato remoto *ebbi* (*ebbe*, *ebbero*).

Chiarimento: In Latino, il perfetto ha *-v-*, ad esempio, *cognōvī*. Ma questo si estendeva a tutte le persone e a tutti(?) i verbi. Se la *-bb-* del passato remoto discende dalla *-v-* del tempo perfetto Latino, perchè la sua distribuzione è così ristretta, a solo poche persone e verbi?

Comment: It is from Latin: from *cognovi* to *conobbi*; from *habui* to *ebbi*. Is that what you meant? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: actually "avere", since it comes from *habeo, -es, habui* made the opposite path: from b to v in the present

Comment: Actually it is common for all romance languages to transliterate between b and v. In Spanish for example the distinction between the two letters has almost disappeared in the last 2 or 3 generations.

Comment: @mau: There's no mystery about the _v_ reflex of Latin _b_ in the case of _avere_ < _habere_.  This is a case of intervocalic spirantization (which has become wholly automatic in Spanish, as Bruno notes immediately above).  _Avere_ preserves _b_ whenever it is geminate: compare present tense 1pl _abbiamo_ with 2pl _avete_.  My question is about the _-bb-_ reflex of perfective _-v-_: which verbs it is confined to and why.

Answer (score 4):

I guess *ebbi*, *ebbe*, *ebbero*, whose *-bb-* comes directly from the *b* of Latin *hab-* root (like *abbiamo*, *abbia* etc.), have influenced the conjugation of *conoscere*, *crescere* and derived verbs (*riconoscere*, *rincrescere* and few others).

Notice that there was a competition between *crebbi* and *crescetti*. The latter sounds really awkward although more regular; in the look for an alternative to the ugly *crescetti*, a solution emerged that was borrowing *-bb-* from the past of *avere* while staying close to the Latin *crēvī*. (Also [*crescei*](http://books.google.it/books?id=SmaKBT_69F0C&lpg=PA692&ots=UzaCN85q6j&dq=crebbi%20crescetti%20crescei&hl=it&pg=PA692#v=onepage&q=crebbi%20crescetti%20crescei&f=false) was among the competitors but it could not prevail.)

Just a hypothesis but it sounds like a reasonable explanation for the unusual "inverse" evolution from *v* to *b* and the gemination of *b*.